# ActiveMQ Artemis queue send security setting

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I have remote ActiveMQ Artemis node which has following security settings

```xml
<security-setting match="#">
   <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
   <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
   <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
   <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
   <permission type="createAddress" roles="admin"/>
   <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admin"/>
   <permission type="consume" roles="admin"/>
   <permission type="browse" roles="admin"/>
   <permission type="send" roles="admin"/>
   <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
   <permission type="manage" roles="admin"/>
</security-setting>
```

But when I send message I get this error:

```
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQSecurityException: AMQ229032: User: admin does not have permission='SEND' on address
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you paste your `login.config` and any related properties files?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your user `admin` is not in the *role* `admin`.

Answer (score 0):

You have something like this in your `broker.xml`:

```
      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="admin"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admin"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="admin"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="admin"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="admin"/>
            <permission type="manage" roles="admin"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>
```

When you create address::queue, such permissions will apply by default, but if in WebUI you performed `addSecuritySettings` operation and did something like this:

```
addressMatch: <your_address>
send: <your_custom_role>
consume: <your_custom_role>
createDurableQueueRoles:
deleteDurableQueueRoles:
createNonDurableQueueRoles:
deleteNonDurableQueueRoles:
manage:
```

Then your `security-settings` in `broker.xml` **are overridden** and they do not have any impact on your created address::queue, causing permissions error when attempting to produce messages to your address::queue using `admin` role.